# RuleFor syntax when working with processed or converted values

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

In FluentValidation does anybody know how I can correct the below syntax:

```
    RuleFor(x =>
        double.Parse(x.MyValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    ).InclusiveBetween(0, 23).WithMessage("Number should be between (0,23]")
     .NotEqual(0).WithMessage("Number cannot be 0");
```

Currently it's not rendering any result in the textbox unless I do:

```
 RuleFor(x => x.MyValue)
```

but `x.MyValue` is a string and I really need to convert it to double. And it's a string on purpose for other reasons unrelated to this.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the value within the lambda expression will cause a mismatch between the ModelState properties and the property being validated.

In your case you must ovveride the rule property name using `WithName(nameof(Model.MyValue))`

The final result will be:

```
RuleFor(x => double.Parse(x.MyValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                .InclusiveBetween(0, 23).WithMessage("Number should be between (0,23]")
                .NotEqual(0)
                .WithMessage("Number cannot be 0")
                .WithName("MyValue");
```